# MVC4 and Razor : how to recover the checked boxes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I've created a table that is diplaying a list of items preceded by a check box for each row.
The displaying is made that way :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "NewInventory";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h3>Select rooms for new inventory</h3>
@Html.Partial("RoomListInventory")
<h3>Select people to assign to</h3>
@Html.Partial("PersonListInventory")
```

In the "main" view and the partial view are, ie :

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Select
            </th>
            <th>
               User name
            </th>
            <th>
               User role
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
               <input type="checkbox" value="1">
            </td>
            <td>
                User 1
            </td>
            <td>
                Role 1
            </td>
        </tr>
        [...]
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My question is : how to recover then, since the value of the check box will be the id of the person, or object or no matter, how to recover with boxes have been selected ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can search through all the checkboxes using  JQuery:

```
var list = $('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked');
var length = list.length;
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
   console.log(list[i].val());
}
```

Note: that you have not supplied a name to the checkbox and as such it will probably not carry over to the server when the form is submitted. Assign it a value to ensure it can be submitted with the form.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="user">
```